# Angular Datatables - Search on keyword causes table to completely disappear from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a search function that I want to use to limit results from a result set that works only when I apply updateFilter() which is triggered from clicking on a category.

Searching by keyword is producing a strange behavior where my table completely disappears.

**What is happening and how do I implement the search function that responds to key presses (characters)?**

```
function updateFilter(){
  $scope.filteredSellerStoreData = $scope.sellerStoreData.filter(function(r) {
    var tag = $scope.filterTag;
    var show = r.TagName == tag;
    return show;
  });




 $scope.searchStore = function(){
      var keywords = $scope.searchQuery.split('');

      if ($scope.searchQuery.trim() == "")
      {
        updateFilter();
        return;
      }
      $scope.filteredSellerStoreData = $scope.sellerStoreData.filter(function(r) {
       res = "";
       found = true;
       for (key in r)
        res += angular.lowercase(r[key]);

       for (w in keywords)
         if (!res.includes(angular.lowercase(keywords[w])))
            return false;
       return true;
      });
    }
```

HTML Snippet

```
  <table  datatable="ng" class="table" >
    <tr style="font-weight: 100;" ng-repeat="data in filteredSellerStoreData" >
    </tr>
    </table>

<input class="form-control" ng-model="searchQuery" ng-change="searchStore()" type="text" placeholder="Search your store" value="" />
```

Comment: I am observing when I type slowly it works, but when I type quickly it disappears.  Do I need a delay?

Comment: I believe I have concluded I need to synchronize my key strokes with the search function.